# Magento 2.3.4 - How to properly remove or uninstalled Temando extension including tables from database?

Tags: composer, magento2.3.4, uninstall-module

I have faced lot issue based on this extension, i can't able to remove by using following cmd,

**composer remove  Temando_Shipping**

Now i just disabled, how to remove properly?

Comment: check this link - https://mirasvit.com/knowledge-base/how-to-remove-magento-2-extension.html

Comment: @MohitPatel Still loading, is it takes more time? Screenshot: https://snipboard.io/6pbWHX.jpg

Comment: @MohitPatel Still loading, is it takes more time to complete the uninstall? almost 30mints loading

Answer (score 1):

`Temando_Shipping` is a normal module in Magento 2.x

However, its problem is that it does install some product attributes in the database.

So besides, the common procedures to remove a module:

```
composer remove <module>
```

This specific module requires you to run the following query:

```
delete from eav_attribute where source_model like '%Temand%';
```

Looking at the database, it looks like the tables:

```
| temando_checkout_address                                |
| temando_collection_point_search                         |
| temando_order                                           |
| temando_order_collection_point                          |
| temando_order_pickup_location                           |
| temando_pickup_location_search                          |
| temando_quote_collection_point                          |
| temando_quote_pickup_location                           |
| temando_shipment                                        |
```

may be good to remove. However, I have never removed them and had my site fine with them. If you do remove the, do make a backup and update us somehow, thanks.

Comment: How to properly remove Temando tables also?

Comment: updated answer @zus

Comment: bro, i can't able to remove, the error: https://snipboard.io/DHhrQ8.jpg

Comment: can't see your error, the link is not showing anything